# Why is bootstrap color class not working with React?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I started with React today and I installed bootstrap using
 `npm install --save bootstrap`
Here is my component.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="badge badge-warning m-1">
          {this.formatCount()}
        </span>
        <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Here is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

My problem is that the color for span i.e badge-warning is not working
[Image of local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOHsY.png)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? secondary is indeed gray so that one does work.

Comment: badge-warning which should be red does not work and shows  white background and white text insead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `badge-warning` to `bg-warning`. [Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/)